# how run pybottle in vagrant

Tags: python, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have this Vagrant file

```
# encoding: utf-8
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    config.ssh.forward_agent = true
    config.vm.boot_timeout = 300
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.30.20"
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 8080
    config.vm.synced_folder "", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"

    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
      apt-get install python-pip build-essential python-dev -y
      pip install bottle
    SHELL

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.name = "M101P"
        v.memory = 524
    end

    config.vm.define :M101P do |t|
        config.vm.hostname = "M101P"
    end
end
```

This is a vagrant machine for learn pybottle...

and i have this code: (hello.py)

```
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

But, when i tray to access to the server, after make

> python hello.py

```
python hello_bottle.py
Bottle v0.12.9 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://localhost:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
```

the server its running, but if y tray to access...

```
curl 192.168.30.20:8080/hello/world
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.30.20 port 8080: Connection refused
```

what i may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The server just binds to localhost which is 127.0.0.1;
if You want to access the server via the server ip You have to change

```
run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

to

```
run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```